# iOS CoreData commit sub transaction but cancel main transaction

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, transactions

I have the following core data model:

A -> B (1 to 1)

A -> C (1 to n)

I created a view controller VC to edit any properties of an instance of A. In that VC I would like to add the possibility to create new instances of C so the user can add new Cs on the fly if necessary. Right now I am doing this by just adding these to the viewContext and saving it. That works but has a little hick up. Once I saved the new C to the context I cannot rollback any changes that have been made to A previously.

So I studied [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145877/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts-2) and found that any changes that I consider separate should be applied in its own child context. I understand that but I still have one question: The tutorial says that any changes made to a childContext are pushed to its parent on save, but it will never be written to disk unless I save the parentContext. Now if I do not want to save the parent context because the user hit the cancel button to rollback other changes, how can I still keep the new Cs?

Answer (score 0):

Don't save data directly to the ManagedObject (CoreData object) for either of the entities A, B or C, rather you should create a model which you should update according to the user input or any data source. You need to create managed objects for A, B or C and set value for respective attributes whenever user confirms to save data. That means if user hits cancel, data won't be saved to CoreData but you will be able to find the previous data in the model throught out the model object lifetime.

Comment: Right now I use the rollback()-method to cancel any changes. However, this may also affect the changes that I actually want to be persisted, e.g. the new Cs. It seems to be very inconvenient to create additional models for each of my core data entities. Is this the only way to achieve what I want?

Comment: In that case @Martin you can create a child managed object context whose parent is main context, make all the changes to child managed object context. When the child managed object context saves its changes, it pushes them to the parent managed object context it’s linked with. The changes are not pushed to the persistent store coordinator until the parent managed object context performs a save operation, pushing its changes to its persistent store coordinator. You can follow the below link https://cocoacasts.com/the-elegance-of-disposable-managed-object-contexts/.